# Wordpress newbie: Not show author, date at top and garbage at bottom of Civi registration profile

Tags: wordpress, profile

First-timer using Wordpress with Civi (and new to WordPress):
We have set up online event registration for a Civi event that is integrated with a (empty, dummy) WordPress site. The registration shows the author and date at the top (minor), and then below the registration profile it shows a bunch of junk at the bottom- a search bar, recent posts, RSS feed, etc. (unacceptable).

How can I have it JUST SHOW the profile questions on the event registration page?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is abut WordPress and the person who asked said he wanted to delete it but couldn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a wp issue, will be standard on all pages unless you remove it from your theme settings on wp.
This has nothing to do with civicrm.

Comment: Ok, apologies! thanks for the response. I voted to delete the post, but it looks like I can't just delete it.